# Automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}[x, y, z]$ over $\mathbb C[x]$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

What are the automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}[x, y, z]$ fixing $\mathbb{C}[x]$? I.e. those automorphisms $\phi:\mathbb{C}[x, y, z]\to\mathbb{C}[x, y, z]$ s.t. $\phi(x) = x$. I am interested in a complete description of this group, similar to the description of $\operatorname{Aut}_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathbb{C}[x, y])$, which is known.

Comment: It embeds in $\mathrm{Aut}_{K}(K[x,y])$ for $K=\mathbf{C}(x)$. If the latter group has a known amalgam decomposition, it at least yields an action of the smaller group on a tree, which ought to yield another description, possibly as amalgam as well.